# Path location error : Program "make" not found in PATH?

Tags: c++, eclipse, blackberry, blackberry-10, momentics

I'm developing a BlackBerry 10 mobile application using the Momentics IDE (native SDK).

After updating the blackberry momentic IDE to handle the new api 10.3.1, All presents project even the new ones, return the eroor below :

***-> "Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type Program "make" not found in PATH   CMAP_LIB            C/C++ Problem"***

How can I fix this ? I hope you can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find out where `make` is in the filesystem and put the path in the `PATH` environment variable, something like:

```
find / -name make 2>/dev/null
```

say you find `make` in `/usr/bin`, then add that directory to `PATH`:

```
PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Actually for a reason that I don't know, when the IDE is being updating, the "make.exe" file of some api was remved from "usr\bin" directory (my app. is running on 10.2 api), so when i replace it, it is fixed.